# Clone javascript object attributes?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, clone

Lets say I have several objects. These objects have four properties each, containing simple integers.
I want to create another object with the highest values for each property, so its a chimeric object. I don't want it to change the originals when I manipulate it and vice versa.

Whats the way to do this in javascript? A simple assignment would create a reference, but I need a duplicate.

PS: Pure JS please, no libraries.

Comment: "*with the highest values*" would not be a clone of anything?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do something like this.

*Updated as per comments*

```
// Source objects.
var objects = [
  { x: 3, y: 4, z: 36 },
  { x: 9, y: 5, z: 9 },
  { x: 1, y: 3, z: 100 },
  { x: 7, y: 0, z: 18 },
];

// Result object.
var result = {
    x: objects[0].x,
    y: objects[0].y,
    z: objects[0].z
};

// Set the maximum value for each property. 
for(var i = 1; i < objects.length; i++){
  result.x = Math.max(result.x, objects[i].x);
  result.y = Math.max(result.y, objects[i].y); 
  result.z = Math.max(result.z, objects[i].z); 
}
```

Comment: `result` will be `Object {x: 9, y: 5, z: 100}`

Comment: @mido22 - no it doesn't.  `Math.max()` works just fine for negative values too.

Comment: @jfriend00 @sam , think about it, if all the values in objects are negative, the result would be ```0,0,0``` (instead of least negative value) which is wrong

Comment: i guess, initializing the result with the vaules of first element in objects would resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the glitch. I initiated the result object by simply copying one of the source objects, generating a completely new object would fix it. Thanks!